# Split out dictionary formatted column into separate column for key and values assosiated with it

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have got data in the following format

| Date | Store_Id | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08-10-2020 | 1 | {"Product_1":{"Size_1":2},"Product_2":{"Size_3":2,"Size_4":10}} |
| 08-10-2020 | 2 | {"Product_3":{"Size_2":2}} |
| 09-10-2020 | 1 | {"Product_1":{"Size_1":2},"Product_3":{"Size_1":2,"Size_2":4,"Size_3":5}} |
| 09-10-2020 | 3 | {"Product_5":{"Size_1":2},"Product_3":{"Size_3":2,"Size_4":10}} |

and want the output such there is a separate column for products, another for their size and one for the quantity at Date - Store_Id level similar to the table shown below:

| Date | Store_Id | Product | Size | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08-10-2020 | 1 | Product_1 | Size_1 | 2 |
| 08-10-2020 | 1 | Product_2 | Size_3 | 2 |
| 08-10-2020 | 1 | Product_2 | Size_4 | 10 |
| 08-10-2020 | 2 | Product_3 | Size_2 | 2 |
| 09-10-2020 | 1 | Product_1 | Size_1 | 2 |
| 09-10-2020 | 1 | Product_3 | Size_1 | 2 |
| 09-10-2020 | 1 | Product_3 | Size_2 | 4 |
| 09-10-2020 | 1 | Product_3 | Size_3 | 5 |
| 09-10-2020 | 3 | Product_5 | Size_1 | 2 |
| 09-10-2020 | 3 | Product_3 | Size_3 | 2 |
| 09-10-2020 | 3 | Product_3 | Size_4 | 10 |

Is there any way to do the above using python?

Comment: What is the input format ?

Comment: You can do it using python, if that is the question. On the how would you do it, that depends on your current data structure. You might want to first undo the nesting of your dictionary, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys)  or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65203641/how-to-convert-a-nested-json-to-the-following-format-in-python3) and then loop over the keys.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your data is formatted as a list like the following one:

```py
items = [
        ["08-10-2020", 1, {"Product_1": {"Size_1": 2},"Product_2": {"Size_3": 2,"Size_4": 10}}],
        ["08-10-2020", 2, {"Product_3" : {"Size_2": 2}}],
        ["09-10-2020", 1, {"Product_1":{"Size_1": 2},"Product_3":{"Size_1": 2,"Size_2": 4,"Size_3": 5}}],
        ["09-10-2020", 3, {"Product_5":{"Size_1": 2},"Product_3":{"Size_3": 2, "Size_4": 10}}]
]
```

You can create another list with the updated items with some for loops:

```py
updated = []

for item in items:
    for product, list_products in item[2].items():
        for size, quantity in list_products.items():
            aux = [item[0], item[1], product, size, quantity]
            updated.append(aux)
```

Now, your data is in the format that you are looking for:

```
>>> print(updated)
['08-10-2020', 1, 'Product_1', 'Size_1', 2]
['08-10-2020', 1, 'Product_2', 'Size_3', 2]
['08-10-2020', 1, 'Product_2', 'Size_4', 10]
['08-10-2020', 2, 'Product_3', 'Size_2', 2]
['09-10-2020', 1, 'Product_1', 'Size_1', 2]
['09-10-2020', 1, 'Product_3', 'Size_1', 2]
['09-10-2020', 1, 'Product_3', 'Size_2', 4]
['09-10-2020', 1, 'Product_3', 'Size_3', 5]
['09-10-2020', 3, 'Product_5', 'Size_1', 2]
['09-10-2020', 3, 'Product_3', 'Size_3', 2]
['09-10-2020', 3, 'Product_3', 'Size_4', 10]
```